# Computing the element-wise logarithm of a matrix exponential more efficiently?

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms, numerical-optimization, matrix-exponential

Is there any known way to compute the element-wise logarithm of a matrix exponential more efficiently?

Motivation:

I am trying to an optimization problem (basically finding a specific Markov embedding). For this I have to evaluate the element-wise logarithm of a matrix exponential a few million times.

Comment: Your matrix is element-wise strictly positive?

Comment: I seriously doubt that there is anything to do other than compute the matrix exponential $\exp(A)$ directly. Even if you had an eigendecomposition $A = CDC^{-1}$ I do not see a way to avoid forming $\exp(A) = C\exp(D)C^{-1}$ and then computing the elementwise logarithm, assuming of course that the entries are (strictly) positive.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, the exponentiated matrices are element-wise strictly positive.